# Overleaf \bibliography for Springer Journal Template

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I am using a Springer journal template where on bibliography section following have been written

```
% BibTeX users please use one of
%\bibliographystyle{spbasic}      % basic style, author-year citations
%\bibliographystyle{spmpsci}      % mathematics and physical sciences
%\bibliographystyle{spphys}       % APS-like style for physics
\bibliography{template.bib}   % name your BibTeX data base

% Non-BibTeX users please use
\begin{thebibliography}{}   
%
% and use \bibitem to create references. Consult the Instructions
% for authors for reference list style.
%
\bibitem{RefJ}
% % Format for Journal Reference
Author, Article title, Journal, Volume, page numbers (year)
% % Format for books
\bibitem{RefB}
Author, Book title, page numbers. Publisher, place (year)
% etc
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
% end of file template.tex
```

On line 4 I have tried mentioning the bib file name both in "template.bib" and "template". Right now it's written "template.bib".

I have erased non bibtex users items as well still unable to see any references while recompiling text.

In the template there are nothin related to bib mentioned except the lines I am showing here.

template.bib have items inside.

After recompiling it's showing [?]

I am new to LaTeX so any assistance will be really helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You need to uncomment one of the three `\bibliographystyle` directives (as well as the `\bibliography` directive, which you say you have already done). You don't mention whether your document has any `\cite` directives; does it? Finally, assuming the document does contain `\cite` directives, have you run LaTeX-BibTeX-LaTeX-LaTeX? Please advise.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes \cite directives were present and the outcome was [?]
After that, I tried all possible combinations from above by commenting out \begin{thebibliography}{} \end{thebibliography}{} and everything inside that, keeping them etc.

Comment: If you want to use BibTeX, you should under no circumstance use `\begin{thebibliography}` and `\end{thebibliography}`. You do need a `\bibliographystyle` directive, though, and you must also run BibTeX. Please provide more information about what you've actually done. A claim such as "I tried all possible combinaions" is *not* useful.

Comment: Thanks for providing the right direction. I have solved it by providing \bibliographystyle{plain} and \bibliography{template} where template.bib was the name of the .bib file.